# std::map conformance of the operator[]

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to solve a bug in my code and it seems that either I can't really understand the requirements for std::map::operator[] in the standard or there is something broken at least in the STL that comes with my compiler (VS2013, still in the process to try different toolsets).

The std::map I'm probably misusing is defined providing a Compare type as its third template parameter that makes some of the key objects I use equivalent with some other. As for my understanding respecting the definition of equivalence given in the standard (23.2.4.2): a and b are equivalent if: `!(a<b)` AND `!(b<a)`.

The problem I'm facing is that, depending on the insertion order, sometime it inserts also keys with an equivalent already there.

Here is the minimal example that I ended up:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <cassert>

struct Foo {
  int x;
  char c;
};

struct FooLess {
  bool equal_c( const Foo& f1, const Foo& f2) const {
    return f1.c == f2.c;
  }

  bool operator() (const Foo& f1, const Foo& f2) const {
    return !equal_c(f1, f2) && f1.x < f2.x;
  }
};

using namespace std;

int main(int , char* [])
{
  FooLess lt;
  assert( !lt( Foo {1, 'a'}, Foo{3, 'a'}) );
  assert( !lt( Foo {3, 'a'}, Foo{1, 'a'}) );

  map<Foo, string, FooLess> m;
    
  m[Foo{ 2, 'b'}] = "Foo(b)"; 
  m[Foo{ 3, 'a'}] = "Foo(A)"; 
  m[Foo{ 4, 'c'}] = "Foo(c)";
  
  // does not hold! 
  assert ((m[Foo{1, 'a'}] == "Foo(A)") );

  m[Foo{ 1, 'a'}] = "Foo(a)"; 
  
  // does not hold!
  assert(m.size() == 3); 
    return 0;
}
```

As for my reading of the standard the assertions should hold.

> 23.4.4.3 map element access [map.access]
> T& operator[](const key_type& x);
>
> 1 Effects: If there is no key equivalent to x in the map, inserts value_type(x, T()) into the map.
>
> 2 Requires: key_type shall be CopyConstructible and mapped_type shall be DefaultConstructible.
>
> 3 Returns: A reference to the mapped_type corresponding to x in *this.
>
> 4 Complexity: logarithmic.

Why Am I wrong? Am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `FooLess` does not describe a strict weak ordering, but a partial ordering.

See [C++ named requirements: Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) for the details.

As an example:

```
Foo a {1, 'a'};
Foo b {2, 'b'};
Foo c {1, 'c'};
FooLess comp;
assert(comp(a, b) && comp(b, c)); // Should imply comp(a, c)
assert(!comp(a, c));              // But doesn't due to only partial ordering
```

Your comparator works as long as all of the keys in the map or searched for have unique `.c`s.

Comment: That is the case of my bug. The sad thing is that I know of that requirement quite well, just didn't figure out the right time. Any suggestion on how to use equivalent keys? so that I can get the value from a or b?  (a and c in your example?)

I'm realizing that I simply can't if the only thing that matter is the Compare.

Comment: @gius The onky specs we have on what you want to be equivalent is code that isn't a strict weak order.  Changing it to a strict weak order changes what it does.  I'd guess what you want is "one of each `c` in the map, but all `c` are found" -- no, finding and replacing are the same logic.  Using `equal_range` to find and picking one yourself may work.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I'm not catching your point. That map definition is in a quite complex code that rely on templates to try to be as declarative as possible. 
I've tried to force the map to behave like it was simply based on equality (if it is the right term for operator==). The easy fix is to switch to std::unordered_map that actually rely on it.

Comment: You could also use a `std::multimap` and just leave the irrelevant parts out of the order, making it a full order with equivalent items.

Comment: @guis Ok, then my guess is wrong.  Regardless **you have to actually describe what you want for people to be able to solve your problem**.  All we have is broken code that does not do what you want.  Making it do what you want requires knowing what you want.  There are infinite possibilities to change your code.